# JS Sencha Touch Charts: max length of label on axis

Tags: javascript, charts, sencha-touch, extjs

i'm working with sencha touch charts. Line chart if to be correctly. My axis labels values is 'Category'. Is there any property to set max length of label ? Lets say 5 symbols. And id label value is more than 5 symbols, then display '...' in the end. Because some times labels a too long, and if so, than they disappear. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.axis.NumericAxis.createLabels()
```

there are the labels created.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, its just saying to look into it more...